# How to create a group that can only manage registered users in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm making a website for a client and Joomla, I want the client to be able to manage users on the site / delete them if necessary, but that is it, I don't want them to be able to see or do anything else on the site, what is the best way of doing that?

Ideally I would have liked to have this done through the front end, I was looking to make a simple list osf users that only the admin group can access and manually delete them from the DB directly, but I'd rather do it through Joomla if that was possible for security reasons.

I looked at ACL's a bit but couldn't really figure out how to limit the functions to what I want, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the front end you won't have much luck with that.  As far as user management all of that is handled on the backend.

If you're looking to do that sort of thing you'll simply have to get much more familiar with the ACL - there's a good amount of documentation on www.joomla.org

Even by utilizing the ACL I don't think there will be much you can do to limit a particular group to having access to JUST the userbase specifically.  The best bet would be to educate your client about Joomla, how it works, what to change, how to change it and why to leave everything else alone.  I know that may be problematic for things in the future, but unfortunately I don't know of any (and have not heard of any) front end solutions for what you're looking to do.  I haven't heard of any back end solutions either however.

I think certain things will be so intertwined to certain levels of permission you won't be able to have that kind of granularity.

**edit: I'm almost 100% positive there's no way this is possible on 1.5.23 (or earlier versions) because the ACL simply isn't there.  So my advice above is aimed specifically at versions up to 1.7.

Comment: I found that if I go to premissiona on each tab and link (article manager, menu manager, extension / module / plugin manager...) and set permissions to denied for admin, everything gets disabled and they can only see the user list and the components list, now the question is, how do I get rid of that component list?

Comment: That is a tough question.  I'm not sure to be honest - wish I had the answer.  Hopefully someone else can chime in!